# Delete All in cakePHP with limit and order

Tags: php, cakephp, sql-delete

I want to know how we can delete data in cakephp by deleteAll with apply order and limit.

**Eg.**

```
DELETE FROM table
[WHERE conditions]
[ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ]]
LIMIT row_count;
```

My code

```
$limit = $location['locationCount']-1;
$delete = $LocationDuplicateTable->deleteAll([
    'customer_id' => $location['customer_id'],
    'store_code' => $location['store_code']
])
->order(['id DESC'])
->limit($limit);
```

This code is not working, means if I add order and limit in deleteAll, it gives error.

I want to add order and limit in deleteAll

Comment: Add details for the statement "This code is not working"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CakePHP Delete with Multiple Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145540/cakephp-delete-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: no @Luuk.......

Comment: Whenever you receive an error, please post the _complete_ error message, and include the related stacktrace (you'll find both in your CakePHP `/logs/`), even if the problem might be obvious to people familiar with CakePHP! Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: deleting data >> https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#deleting-data